# `serverless login` return Error: spawn /home/imin/.serverless/bin/xdg-open ENOENT

Tags: lubuntu, xdg-open

As a linux newbie, I tried installing lubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64 in my VMware to do my development work there. Installation is a breeze, now I'm trying to install Serverless as per the guide here https://serverless.com/framework/docs/getting-started/

I run the command `curl -o- -L https://slss.io/install | bash` to install Serverles without any problem. After installation, I closed the terminal and opened a new one and I can run `serverless` command without any problem. However, when I tried to run this command `serverless login`, it will display:

```
Serverless: Logging you in via your default browser...
If your browser does not open automatically, please open it &  open the URL below to log in:
https://serverlessinc.auth0.com/authorize?blablabla

Error: spawn /home/imin/.serverless/bin/xdg-open ENOENT
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              12.16.1
     Framework Version:         1.67.3 (standalone)
     Plugin Version:            3.6.6
     SDK Version:               2.3.0
     Components Version:        2.29.0
```

I checked inside `/home/imin/.serverless/bin/` and couldn't find xdg-open , so I run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdg-utils`, closed and reopen the terminal, and run the command `serverless login` again but the same error is still being displayed. Being a newbie who thought there's a problem with my lubuntu installation, I downloaded linux mint xcfe and tried installing serverless and running the same command, and not-voila, got the same exact error.

What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by finding xdg-open with

```
which xdg-open
```

Then creating a symlink where needed

```
ln -s /usr/bin/xdg-open /home/USER/.serverless/bin/xdg-open
```

after it worked with no issue